# How to bootstrap python pyramid in unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

How can I load/bootstrap the Pyramid settings in the .ini files, before running a unit test, such that the logging settings in the ini file are used (I am pyramid newbie)?

I thought this should be done through "pyramid.paster" like this:

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
bootstrap("../development.ini")
```

but it shows an error, like this:

```
  File "..env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 514, in _context_from_explicit
    "No loader given in section %r" % section)
```

Also if I load it like this:

```
from pyramid.paster import get_appsettings
settings = get_appsettings('../development.ini', name='main')
bootstrap(settings)
```

How should I perform this

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your main section name, like this:

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstra
bootstrap("../development.ini#main")
```

per `pyramid.paster` [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/paster.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that only includes the app:main section not? I want that the logging section is included such that the console logging is used. How can I do that? And I want to put mail settings in the ini file that is used in the  views.py